# Netboot - How to set a static IP

Tags: networking, centos

I've modified a CentOS net install image to load my kickstart file over http. This works great when running on a network that has a DHCP server. Obviously, without DHCP this fails because the installer can't acquire an IP.

So, my question is what do I need to modify in order to set a static IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass the static IP options to the kernel so that the kickstart process can locate your ks.cfg. As you know, by default the net install looks for a dhcp address. You can set a static address by passing at a minimum `ip` and optionally `gw` & `dns` at the boot prompt.

`linux ks=http://192.168.0.1/ks.cfg ip=192.168.0.100 gw=192.168.254.254 dns=192.168.0.2`

You can optionally specify the device to use in one of 5 ways.

```
ksdevice=<device>
```

- the device name of the interface, for example, eth0
- the MAC address of the interface, for example, 00:12:34:56:78:9a
- the keyword `link`, which specifies the first interface with its link
  in the up state
- the keyword `bootif`, which uses the MAC address that pxelinux set in
  the BOOTIF variable. Set IPAPPEND 2 in your pxelinux.cfg file to have pxelinux set the
  BOOTIF variable.
- the keyword `ibft`, which uses the MAC address of the interface
  specified by iBFT

There are *many many* options you can pass for a kickstart boot. You can get a full list of the boot and kickstart script options for RHEL/CentOS 6 [here](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-startinginstall.html).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Do you know if you can also specify what device you want to use?

Comment: Sure can. See my edit.

Comment: This is great info uther. I also really appreciate you linking to the RHEL documentation. I had googled around but never came across it.

Comment: You need a netmask as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is some ways that on a CentOS system you can set IP addresses staticlly, I mention two of these:

1) using command-line:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth1 192.168.30.40 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.30.255
```

in this command you can set your intended static ip address in place of 192.168.30.40, netmask in place of 255.255.255.0 and broadcast in place of 192.168.30.255 .

2)GUI-based:
enter the following command as root:

```
/usr/bin/neat
```

now you see a window, select the interface you want to set a static IP to it (e.g. eth0) then press the "Edit" key. now another window will open, in this one select "Staticlly Set IP Addresses" radio button, then fill "IP address", "Subnet Mask", "Default Gateway Address" fields as you want. then press OK to save changes.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I wasn't familiar with neat. Good to know.

Comment: As I said its a GUI-based utility, no familiarity is needed, enter the above command, and set IP.